# Abstract Algebra- Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm stuck on the following questions "In the alternating group $A_4$, let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup generated by $(123)$. Find all the right cosets of $H$ and all the left cosets of $H$. Is every right coset also a left coset."

The answer is as follows "$H = [idx_4 , (123), (132)]$ so each coset will have order 3, and since
$|A_4| = 12$ there will be 4 distinct cosets. We find the following right
cosets:

$H = [idx_4 , (123), (132)]$

$H(234) =[ (234), (12)(34), (134)]$

$H(124) = [(124), (13)(24), (243)]$

$H(143) = [(143), (14)(23), (142)]$

and the following left cosets:

$H = [idx_4 , (123), (132)]$

$(234)H = [(234), (13)(24), (142)]$

$(124)H = [(124), (14)(23), (134)]$

$(143)H = [(143), (12)(34), (243)]$

and we see that $H$ is the only coset that is both a left and a right coset."

Now I understand how you find the left and right cosets, the thing I'm stuck on is why did they choose $(234), (124), (143)$ out of the possible options from the alternating group $A_4$ as the permutations that $H$ is used on?

Comment: The choice is *so to say* arbitrary. You could have also picked others and you would have obtained the same result. Try it out by picking $(12)(34)$ and so on.\\ Basically you start by choosing $H$ as first coset. Then you choose any element not in $H$ and take its coset, then take an element which is not in $H$ nor in the previously constructed coset and do its coset, and so on and so forth. Keeping this line of thought going you will end up finding all cosets.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because $3$-cycles generate the alternating group. In the case of $A_4$ there are only $8$ $3$-cycles, $(123),(124), (134), (234)$ and their inverses. So taking $3$ of them (different from $(123)$ and its inverse) is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The choice was to an extent arbitrary. The fact is any single element from each coset can be chosen to represent it.

If your question is as to how to find these elements, you can work recursively. The easiest coset to find is $H$ itself. To find the next coset, pick any element $a_1$ not in $H$. This will give you a new coset. To find all of the elements in this coset, multiply $a_1$ on the left or right (depending on whether you're doing right or left cosets) by every element of $H$.

Suppose you've found $n$ cosets $Ha_0,\ldots,Ha_n$. Following this procedure, you'll also know all of the elements in the union of these cosets. If you pick one element $a_{n+1}$ not in the union, this will give you a new coset. If the union is the entire group, then you've found all of the cosets.

Comment: Alright that makes sense, I just thought it was weird that every permutation they chose in the question was of order 3, and that the cosets they produced all had order 3, then 2, then 3 again.

Comment: @Jimmie Unless the subgroup is normal there's not much to say about the orders of the elements of the coset. One wouldn't call this a coincidence exactly but as far as I know there's no deep reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how much group theory you have covered until now, but if you consider the subgroup of $A_{4}$ 
$$
V = \{ 1, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23) \},
$$
you will have $$\{ v h : v \in V, h \in H\} 
=
V H = A_{4} = H V = \{ h v : v \in V, h \in H\},$$ with $V \cap H = \{ 1 \}$.

So, although as noted in other answers there are many choices for sets of representatives of the left and right cosets (actually $3^{4}$ choices for each set!), the set $V$ is somewhat a natural choice.